# Uploading a File to database in django from Google drive

Tags: python, django, postgresql, file-upload, google-drive-api

As the title suggest, I am trying to figure out how to upload from google drive to my database in PostgreSQL and have gotten nowhere. Would really appreciate some direction.

Comment: Can you explain more what you have tried and what  you are using>

Comment: I tried these: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python
https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#api-key

I am using Django(Python) on visual studio code (Windows).